# Unity3D how to make an object start moving in an arc or circle using radius?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, unity-game-engine

Unity3D, C#

I would like to know how to move the object smoothly using radius, I want the object to start moving in a circle from the transform.position, like this:[sample of what I want to do](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Lo6wG.png), and only using C# script, what I can think of is using transform like below.

```
timeCounter += Time.deltaTime * speed;
float x = Mathf.Cos(timeCounter) * width;
float z = Mathf.Sin(timeCounter) * height;
transform.position = new Vector3(x, 0, z);
```

I have tried this https://forum.unity.com/threads/how-to-make-an-object-move-in-a-circular-motion-at-constant-speed.526107/ but it is not what I wanted, the answer of mine (https://youtu.be/V2A-0yOUNwc) make the object quickly move to the right and it uses the middle location as the center then starts moving from the right, and I can't control which angle it will start.

Answer (score 1):

Try `Transform.RotateAround`:

```
using UnityEngine;

public class RotateAround : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Vector3 rotatingPoint;
    private Vector3 rotAxis = new Vector3(0,1,0);
    void Start()
    {
        
    }
    void Update()
    {
        transform.RotateAround(rotatingPoint, rotAxis, 1f);   
    }
}
```

Check the [documentation](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Transform.Rotate.html). You set the rotation poiunt,the rotation axis and the angle and that is it.